# How to apply CSS properties of one class in another

Tags: css

I would like to know how I can apply the CSS of one class in another. I did little bit of research on this and I found two solutions.

1. Using [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)
2. Specify both the classes like class="content colorTxt"

Unfortunately I cannot use both these options. Because I have permission to edit only the CSS files. So it would be great if you can let me know if there is any other option. Something like below:

```
.colorTxt{
color: Blue;
}

.content, .colorTxt
{

}
```

I tried this option, but it doesn't work. Please let me know what can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're trying to achive is not possible with pure CSS.

There is one case when **.content** is the descendant of **.colorTxt**, but even then all that you can is inherit some know properties of **.colorTxt**, nothing more.

```
<div class="colorTxt">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>

.colorTxt { color: blue; }
.content { color: inherit; }
```